# urlencode issues

Tags: php, mysql

I write this simple script to log ad/link clicks and having trouble with long urls or urls with special char(s) ex : ? = etc which breaks the redirect and only loads the domain part.

So I'm trying to get urlencode to work. I have tried two ways so far and neither are working.
I kno mysql_query is outdated still learning

current code :

```
<?php
require('config.php');

    // Update Ad Pull/Display count
    $AdID= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['AdID']);
    $UpdateADHitDisplay = mysql_query("UPDATE ads SET clicks = clicks +1 WHERE ID = '$AdID'");

    // Get Redirection Inforamtion
    $RedirectURL = $_GET['RedirectURL'];
    //$FixedURL = urlencode($RedirectURL); // this way didn't work
        function url_encode($RedirectURL){ // then tried to use it as a function and no go either.
         return urlencode(utf8_encode($RedirectURL));
     }
    header("Location: $RedirectURL");

?>
```

database Layout :

```
•Table : ads 
•Row : clicks
```

example of passed link : `http://yourdomain.com/clickcounter.php?AdID=43&RedirectURL=http://stackoverflow.com`

Example of trouble link : `https://www.demoexample.com/index.aspx?d=111&prog_id=tttt`

Comment: Please give an exact example of a URL that fails to redirect.  (I notice that although your are defining a function `url_encode()`, you are not actually _calling_ the function)

Comment: It should not be necessary to urlencode() the URL before redirecting.

Comment: Between these two, I would expect the first to be problematic, not the second, if either was.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean if either was. -

Comment: I mean I don't expect either of these to cause any problem.  `$_GET` params are automatically `urldecode()`ed.  The second url you posted `demoexample.com`, is that the contents of `RedirectURL`?

Comment: "Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs." When you encode the URL in the redirect you are also encoding the :// which of course would break the URL. As Michael said, there is no reason to encode the URL. Using the redirect is the same as someone pasting the URL in their addressbar, no need to do encoding =o)

Comment: then why isnt it working? werid

Comment: after a lot of testing i found its not passing & signs. which is needed for the ads how can I make it pass &

Comment: so its thiking its another GET but how can I tell it to take the entire url string